# What happens if I use the travel system to access DLC content before I unlock the travel system in the plot?

Tags: borderlands

I'm at the second playthrough for my level 43 Soldier and my mission log says I'm at the "Getting Lucky" mission. I could do that, or I could access my DLC by using the fast travel system.

...except I *haven't* unlocked the fast travel system yet in the plot!

[image]

This looks eerily like a one-way trip... or is it? What happens if I take the plunge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a one way trip - the fast travel nodes in the DLC content are always enabled, regardless of your progress in the main story line, as the DLC is treated as completely separate from the story line with only a few minor restrictions (like level) in order to access them.

For example, I created a new character and went off to Mad Moxxie's Underdome, not only was I allowed to travel to the Underdome (even though I hadn't unlocked the fast travel system and my fast travel list looked like your screenshot but with all of the DLC travel points in it) and travel back using the fast travel system at the Underdome.

Comment: FWIW this is true in Borderlands 2 as well

Comment: One minor side-note - I took a trip to Jakobs Cove in the middle of playthrough 1. It worked fine, but unfortunately, it locked the Jakobs Cove location into the middle of my list of locations. Any new locations I visited were placed after Jakobs Cove, but before the rest of the DLC (which stayed at the bottom of the list). So you may want to hold off on taking the trip until after you've reached every area in the main game, just to keep your list a bit tidier.